# Nesting databases and using the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nested, html-table

I'm new to rails, 2nd week at it actually - I'm in an academy, and I've hit a wall.

I have 2 databases, posts and comments ... comments belongs_to post and post has_many comments.

I've gotten my last 10 posts to list and I've gotten comments to list out underneath them.

My question is I think one of logic.  How should I call the data so my comments will list under their respective posts?  I think I'm close.  I have them listing out for posts but they are listing in the wrong places.  I can't seem to figure out how to get them to the right place.

Along with a solution should you provide one, please share with me your thought process on getting the answer.

I drew number charts and I believe I figured out that when the Post.user_id is equal to the User.id I'm posting on (I think that's right, still a little confused), that should be when to drop the comment?

My code originally looked like this in the index.html.erb of Posts:

```
<tbody>
<% @posts.last(10).each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.body %></td>
    <td><%= post.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

```
<ul>
<h2> Followed Posts </h2>
<% current_user.followeds.each do |user| %>
  <% user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <li><%= post.body %> | <%= post.user_id %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

```
<ul>
<h2> Comments </h2>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <li><%= comment.body %> <%= comment.id %> <%= comment.user_id %> <%= comment.post_id %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have been trying something like this now for the comments - it's actually for a different project but the same setup.  I did the above part once again to try to solve the problem and get more practice ... I'm at the same place with the same goal for both projects right now:

```
<ul>
    <% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
        <li>
            <%= post.title %><br>
            <%= post.body %><br>
        <!-- if there is a comment for a post - post it here -->
        <!-- if there is a comment for the Post_id, Output it here --> 
                <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
                    <%= comment.body %> <%= comment.id %>
                    <br>
                <% end %>

        <div class="post-link"> 
        <%= link_to "Comment", new_post_comment_path(post) %> |
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %> |
            <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Confirm you want to delete."} %> 
      </div>
  </li>
    <%end%>
```

I posted a little of my thought process commented out in the code.
Like I said, something wrong in my logic I believe since the comments are in the wrong place. 
No particular pattern though.

Output is like this:

4
Best new PS4 games - post.title
The Last of Us, Battlefield 4, Assassin's Creed 4, in that order. - post.body

---many comments end up jumbled below - comment.body and comment.id

it does work, kind of
yes! Apps? I love apps! Post number 2 here for Nate comment 3 for Nate 1 More sunglass comments Commenting on my own comment

4
High school is boring - post.title

I hate having to go to school everyday. All I really want to do is sleep in as long as I want and then play video games. I think I'm going to be a professional video game player someday. There is such a thing as that, isn't there.  -  post.body

--- many comments jumbled below - comment.body and comment.id

sunglasses? Assassins creed! Hunting is cool. I hunted in florida I hate hs too

---

So still trying to clarify the output:

It posts the Post.body

But then it may or may not post comments that should be assigned to this post.

Another Post

Comments that refer to this post and others end up here.

Another Post

Comments that belong to different posts end up here.
(so every comment is not where it should be. Maybe my loop is not set up right and in the wrong place but I've tried a lot so far to get the right output)

---

Well, I noticed for comments, the user_id and post_id are both identical as well 1 1 or 2 2, is that right?

Comment: What you call databases are actually Tables, just fyi. I think we are all a bit confused on your example, please be more concise/direct when asking something, ambiguous logic questions are hard to answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, what can I do to clarify? I would like comments to appear under their respective posts.  Hope that helps. I will do my best, I've been trying to figure this out a few days now, granted I started a new project to work my way back to see if i forgot anything, thanks again, especially for clarifications (tables, thanks)

Comment: Maybe format the wrong output in a better format, don't make us read too much text that we are not familiar with. i.e. "Post 1, Comment A, Comment B, etc. etc, use bullets, space", etc. it is very painful to parse your output :), regards

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've reformatted the output so hopefully it's more understandable ... if it clarifies the question, I'm trying to make all comments for post 1 list underneath and all comments for post 2 list underneath etc etc ... I'm not sure how to logically make that happen